# Laravel - Help eager loading secondary relationships (I currently have 364 SQL queries running)

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm bulding the admin side of a site in Laravel 4 and am trying to make everything work within eloquent. I am trying to build an object with several relationships. This seems to work fine until I try to load a secondary relationship.

Here is my call to the YourDetail Model:

```
$applicants = YourDetail::with(array('User', 'Application', 'SecondaryEds', 'SecondaryEds.SecondaryTypes', 'SecondaryEds.SecondaryGrades', 'FurtherEds', 'FurtherEds.FurtherTypes', 'FurtherEds.FurtherGrades', 'UniEds', 'UniEds.UniClassifications', 'UniEds.UniQualifications', 'WorkExperiences', 'WhyYou', 'StartDate', 'Referer'))->whereIn('user_id', $applicants);
```

All my relationships are defined within the various models and work fine when used directly. The issue I'm having is with the secondary relationships, e.g.

> FurtherEds.FurtherTypes, FurtherEds.FurtherGrades,
>   UniEds.UniClassifications, UniEds.UniQualifications,

etc.

Now when I just run the query i get exactly what I would expect - around 20 Select queries representing the various models, the select query produced which brings in the 'FurtherEds.FurtherGrades' Model for example looks like this:

```
select * from `further_grades` where `further_grades`.`deleted_at` is null and `further_grades`.`id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

**So far so good...**

The problem comes when I try to access these models through the collection object;

So lets say I now loop through my collection passing each object to a view like so:

```
foreach($applicants as $applicant){
    View::make('ApplicantView', compact('applicant'));
}
```

and then within my view I try to loop through the FurtherEds and echo out a property of the FurtherGrades model:

*ApplicantView.blade.php*

```
@foreach($applicant->FurtherEds as $fe)
    {{ $fe->FurtherGrades->name }}
@endforeach
```

This will now create a new sql query for each applicant despite my attempts at eager loading, e.g.

```
select * from `further_grades` where `further_grades`.`deleted_at` is null and `further_grades`.`id` = ? limit 1 (for each applicant)
```

The end result is my page is currently producing 364 select queries, which although the page load speeds aren't bad seems a tad excessive.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here and point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To anyone interested...

I have now solved this issue:

it appears what I was doing was loading in the relationships correctly but accessing them incorrectly. So for example if you eager load the relationship like so:

```
$applicants = YourDetail::with('FurtherEds.FurtherTypes', 'FurtherEds.FurtherGrades');
```

You should then access the elements like so:

```
@foreach($applicants as $applicant)
@foreach($applicant->FurtherEds as $fe)
  {{ $fe->FurtherTypes->name }}
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

The issue I had was in accessing the lower models with the wrong capitalisation:

eg.

```
@foreach($applicants as $applicant)
@foreach($applicant->furtherEds as $fe)
  {{ $fe->furtherTypes->name }}
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Laravel is clever enough to recognise the relationships in the models still so it knows what to access but it does not recognise `$applicant->furtherEds` as being the same as the eager loaded model object `$applicant->FurtherEds` this instead produces fresh sql queries.

By the time I had done this a few times on a mildly complex page I had 2000+ sql queries. Lesson learnt... never again

p.s. now I've worked out how to use it properly Eloquent is officially the best thing ever and definitely worth persevering with if your having trouble.

Comment: this instead produces fresh sql queries -> this is not true... Laravel won't produce new query if you have eager loaded model relations

Comment: ^^May be fixed in newer versions of eloquent, please dont just state it's not true, it certainly was in the version used if accessed using StudlyCaps model names

Answer (score 1):

Try loading secondary related models like this:

```
// from the docs
You may even eager load nested relationships:

$books = Book::with('author.contacts')->get();
```

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I'm doing? Only difference seems to be that I have an array of relationships. If I'm mistaken please could u Elaborate on where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't notice that you have this in your array: `FurtherEds.FurtherGrades`. I will test this with actual code and will let you know if I come up with something

Comment: The array is used for adding eager load constraints.  It should be fie if you take away the array, though I'm not sure it would help... it might.  Also, for example, loading `author.contacts` would automatically load the `authors` relationship as well, so you could take those singles out that you have.  That might be the source of the additional queries being ran.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I have tried to simplify the issue so now I am just loading one nested relationship (belongsTo and belongsTo) and passing the relationship into it within a with() method (as above -no array) and still I have multiple select queries picking out the secondary relationships individually by id. (this come after the query which picks them all out. It seems that as soon as I try to access those relationships it produces a fresh query... any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should raise an issue on github about this? I was searching through the issues and did not find this to be reported by now.

Comment: You may be right... it seems to only happen when I try to loop through the object from within a (blade)view - If I loop through the object in my model or controller it doesn't produce additional queries

Comment: Hey guys, I've updated with an answer if anyone's interested... thanks for all your help